# Fastest way to download multiple urls

Tags: php, performance

I have a web portal that needs to download many of separate json files and display their contents in a sort of form view.  By lots I mean 32 separate files minimum.

I've tried cUrl with brute force iteration and its taking ~12.5 seconds.

I've tried curl_multi_exec as demonstrated here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php with the function below and its taking ~9 seconds.   A little better but still terribly slow.

```
function multiple_threads_request($nodes){
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    $curl_array = array();
    foreach($nodes as $i => $url)
    {
        $curl_array[$i] = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl_array[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curl_array[$i]);
    }
    $running = NULL;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh,$running);
    } while($running > 0);

    $res = array();
    foreach($nodes as $i => $url)
    {
        $res[$url] = curl_multi_getcontent($curl_array[$i]);
    }

    foreach($nodes as $i => $url){
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $curl_array[$i]);
    }
    curl_multi_close($mh);
    return $res;
}
```

I realize this is an inherently expensive operation but does anyone know any other alternatives that might faster?

EDIT: In the end, my system was limiting curl_multi_exec and moving the code to a production machine saw dramatic improvements

Comment: Must it be done in the backend? Why don't you move the fetching to the client? Some AJAX magic, backbone views and your basically done. In waaaay less then 9 seconds. ;-)

Comment: yeah...i thought about that but i'd have to refactor easily ~75% of my work which I can't do in the short term.  Longer term, that's definitely what I should do.

Comment: Is caching an option? Either explicitly, or implicitly. (It is largely orthogonal to moving fetches to the client-side.)

Comment: Well, must the information provided by those sources be accurate? You could fetch those in a cron job (e.g. every minute or every hour, depending on your needs) and include the aggregated JSON in your serverside code.

Comment: does not sound like something i would do per user request, cache\stoer, retrive perodically

Comment: Try it with 32 times the same fast site, let's say google.com. Still 9 sec?

Comment: @user2864740 cannot be cached.  Must be accurate to the moment in time.  again, I know its inherently expensive....just trying to do the least crappy thing available

Comment: If you went from 12.5 to 9 seconds then does that mean your longest cURL request is 9 seconds and the other 31 are less than 9? Is there a cURL limit when using `curl_multi_init()`?

Comment: @user2191572 `does that mean your longest cURL request is 9 seconds` yeah, this is likely

Comment: @hek2mgl - tried that. slower.  14.3 sec

Comment: @user2191572 good question.  This is a blocking call for the page being built so I'm not sure.  I'm measuring with google developer tools Network tab...have a better suggestion there?

Comment: Have you tried to investigate using wireshark? sometimes it's a slow DNS which causes that

Comment: Well, I'd still cache it and fetch it periodically. 30 seconds should give you accurate enough data and enough time to fetch.

Comment: @hek2mgl yea it sounds like it so if it is true then the only reasonable answer is for OP to cURL with sites that have better bandwidth or maybe OP's bandwidth isn't up to par.

Comment: all the files are less than 100kb

Comment: @Brad, are you familiar with wireshark?

Comment: @hek2mgl Seen and heard of it, never used it...i'll check it out

Comment: I would give it a try. It's pretty self explaining and you need to see the network traffic under the hood in order to fix the problem. Another idea would be to run your script using `strace php multi.php` and post the (large) output to a pastebin

Comment: @hek2mgl check out the comments under the benchmarking answer I provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely look into benchmarking your cURLs to see which one has the slowdown but this was too lengthy for a comment so let me know if it helps or not:

```
// revert to "cURLing with brute force iteration" as you described it :)

$curl_timer = array();

foreach($curlsite as $row)
{
    $start = microtime(true);

    /**
     * curl code
     */

    $curl_timer[] = (microtime(true)-$start);
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($curl_timer, true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: The slowest one is ~600ms.  Fastest was 200.  Average was apx 250ms

Comment: So ~8 seconds for 32 iterations when done one at a time?

Comment: 9.22 seconds actually...but yeah.

Comment: All together should take ~600ms.

Comment: interesting.  I'm on a VM for now...running apache2.  Maybe I should deploy the curl_multi_exec solution to my server and see how it performs...

Comment: @Brad It would be interesting to know the results

Comment: using curl directly with no php from the linux terminal with those urls is taking ~5 seconds.  deploying now to see how a real machine performs

Comment: Testing it on the real server will definitely prove useful. You could be having a bandwidth limitation issue locally especially if you are using DSL, Satellite internet, or going through a VPN for work or anything.