# High performance method for downloading large images to PHP server from URL

Tags: php, curl, download, wget

I have an arrray with about 100 links to images. The images are about 5-10 MB. I want to loop through the array and download all the pictures to my server. I have found several ways of doing it and started with `file_get_contents` but it eats my memory.

I have also looked at

Wget

```
shell_exec('wget -O /var/www/html/images/image.gif http://www.google.com/images/logo_sm.gif');
```

PHP Copy

```
copy('http://example.com/image.php', 'local/folder/flower.jpg');
```

CULR

```
$url  = 'http://www.google.com/images/logo_sm.gif';
$path = '/var/www/html/images/images.gif';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents($path, $data);
```

Each user has their "own" array (different image links). What is the fastest way to download the pictures to my server and require minimum performance (low memory usage, etc.)

Comment: Lowest performance? You mean highest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time the `cURL/wget/copy` approaches and see: they'll have "roughly the same" throughput and they won't use excessive memory<sup>1</sup>. However,

these new approaches *suffer from the same problem*; the downloads occur in series.

(While there are a number of factors involved, including bandwidth/latency, and distribution between servers/handlers, *adding some degree of parallelism will be the single biggest method of improving the overall throughput*.)

#### wget + parallel spawns

There are several methods to [start generic parallel processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35956/is-there-parallel-wget-something-like-fping-but-only-for-downloading) which can be used with shell_exec and wget. These approaches can spawn the (wget) processes in parallel.

Because of the loss of direct access to what a particular process is doing this also involves finagling output redirection/processing. On the other hand, it is a 'relatively simple' change from a one-shot shell exec.

The shell exec itself should also be hardened against injection attacks; security should not be discounted when using such shell access.

#### cURL + multi exec

The more lucrative (and initially complicated) approach is to use [`curl_multi_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php). Unlike `curl_exec`, multi exec allows curl to be processed in an async manner and thus supports parallel operations.

The process is a bit convoluted, but [a generic example can be found here](http://www.askapache.com/php/curl-multi-downloads.html); and there are some related questions on SO (although I have yet to find a 'killer question/answer' for this specific problem):

- [understanding php curl_multi_exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559157/understanding-php-curl-multi-exec)
- [Fastest way to download multiple urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959178/fastest-way-to-download-multiple-urls)

An implementation would probably also want to limit the number of parallel cURL requests.

I recommend cURL because it avoids having to be 'extra careful' when dealing with the shell. If the shell exec must be used, then consider saving the file list/targets to a file first and then feeding that in via `xargs` or whatnot. Using cURL also allows associated feedback for individual requests.

Since this operation is likely bound to 'take some time' the downloading should probably be done via a queue / off-request mechanism .. but that's a different architectural can of worms.

---

<sup>1</sup> The problem with `file_get_contents` is that it will fetch the downloaded data as a string which can cause 'out of memory' conditions, depending file size and PHP environment.

However, none of the cURL/wget/open approaches (when done correctly) have this problem as they stream directly to a file. (In the question the cURL can run out of memory because it does not correctly stream to a file but rather invokes `file_put_contents` after the entire file is already downloaded into memory.)